# Three.js Mesh animation and texture mapping

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I did some research and learn how to export the obj file to .js file that can be imported by JSON model of Three.js. but how can you animated such model ? I have a bird model in .js format i need to learn to flap its wings. Further more when i downloaded the obj file from the internet as it was free model it also contains texture images for the object but when i import the obj in 3d modelling software Blender 3d, it cannot load the texture but it has the location right inside the obj file when i open it from text editor. When i convert it to .js format it also has right location located to the bmp images for texture mapping, but fail to load when i load the model in webgl, using JSON Model.

Can anyone please point me in right direction from where i can learn all this thinks, it would be even great if you know and help me right away in answer. Please, I need help form you guys .

Code of the Js model file

```
{
    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3,
        "generatedBy" : "Blender 2.66 Exporter",
        "vertices" : 2652,
        "faces" : 4798,
        "normals" : 2652,
        "colors" : 0,
        "uvs" : [1202],
        "materials" : 4,
        "morphTargets" : 0,
        "bones" : 0
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default0",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-201.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },
    {
        "DbgColor" : 15597568,
        "DbgIndex" : 1,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default1",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-200.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },
    {
        "DbgColor" : 60928,
        "DbgIndex" : 2,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default2",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-202.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },
    {
        "DbgColor" : 238,
        "DbgIndex" : 3,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-203.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },

    {
        "DbgColor" : 15658496,
        "DbgIndex" : 4,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default0",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-201.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },

    {
        "DbgColor" : 61166,
        "DbgIndex" : 5,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default1",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-200.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },

    {
        "DbgColor" : 15597806,
        "DbgIndex" : 6,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default2",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-202.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    },

    {
        "DbgColor" : 419610,
        "DbgIndex" : 7,
        "DbgName" : "_5___Default",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "n-203.bmp",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 2,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphnormals.html
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_horse.html

In the first example look here,line 90

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader.load( "models/animated/flamingo.js", function( geometry ) {

                    morphColorsToFaceColors( geometry );
                    geometry.computeMorphNormals();

                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, morphTargets: true, morphNormals: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
                    var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );

                    meshAnim.duration = 5000;

                    meshAnim.scale.set( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
                    meshAnim.position.y = 150;

                    scene1.add( meshAnim );
                    morphs.push( meshAnim );

                } );
```

Comment: yes i did read those codes but there is nothing there, just some scaling and positioning of loaded model and the function which i cannot understand named as morphColorsToFaceColors()